# Oracle Scheduler - can a single job be both event based and time based

Tags: oracle, events, scheduler, jobs, schedule

Hi I am new to Oracle Scheduler. My question is - Can we give both repeat interval and event condition in the Schedule object for a single job?

I have this requirement in job scheduling - A job should run at a scheduled time, but only if a certain event has occured.

For eg.

Job1 should run 
- at 10 am every day
- but only if same job from yesterday is not running anymore. (This I gonna figure out based on the table entry.) So the event gonna be a cell entry say 'ENDED' in the table job_statuses.

Would be easier if I can give both info in the same job. Else another approach I gonna try is -  Schedule the job based on time. If the earlier instance is still running , reschedule the job based on event. But this looks clumsy.

Thanks in advance.

Mayank

Comment: Try to use Job Chain for this. You can define chain rules and dependencies between jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd encode the condition in the PL/SQL of the procedure itself. i.e. it runs at 10am every day, but the first thing it does is check if the previous job had finished successfully.

Comment: Yeah, thats the second approach I was talking about. But that would mean, if the previous job is not done, I'll need to create a new job checking for 'previous job complete' event, running only once.

Comment: Conceptually, I'd separate the job from the task itself; every time the job runs, it first works out what task (or tasks) have not yet been done, and does them. If it fails, the next time the job runs, it will see that the tasks that the previous job was supposed to do were not done, and will try to do them again. Something like what ik_zelf has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create 3 jobs

1. EVENT_JOB
2. REPEAT_JOB
3. ACTUAL_WORK_JOB

EVENT_JOB and REPEAT_JOB just start ACTUAL_WORK_JOB. If that is already - or still -  running, you get an error on which you can react accordingly.